# jQuery event binding management

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="some-class">content</span>
  ..n span repetitions..
</div>
```

Given the following .on()

```
$('.some-class').on('click', function () { ... });
```

If you redraw the `.container` with new `span.some-class`, will you leak the old events?

What I mean is, before the redraw, should you do:

```
$('.some-class').off('click');
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should check out event delegation:
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 2):

If you attach your event listener like this:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {
        // ...
    }
}, '.some-class');
```

Then your event listener will not "leak" as you put it.  You can redraw, add additional elements with `.some-class` and they will all inherit the event listener.  This has the added benefit of only registering one event listener instead of "x" listeners depending on how many `.some-class` elements there are.  Much better performance.

Comment: It also adds the benefit of not having to perform a dom lookup